# Analysis of Time Series data

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, decomposition

I want to determine an appropriate model for daily stock index having the graph given below.
    It could be seen that the data has a trend but does it have seasonality too. If so what model is it i.e (additive or multiplicative ) and what would be the frequency of seasonality?

I ran a periodogram and it showed a spike only at 0. Also, its ACFs are all positive and is gradually decreasing.

Comment: Did you try ARIMA ?

Comment: Well, I've been told to decompose using a multiplicative or additive model.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick and easy way to handle time series is with Facebook's package called `Prophet`. Simply feed in your daily data in correct format, and it will make predictions. You don't need to feed any ACF/seasonality info...it should find it automatically for you.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prophet/index.html

You can also consider options like recurrent neural network using package `Keras`. Or consider `ARIMA` functions like `auto.arima`. I have had good results using algorithm called `TBATS` as well. Just try them all and choose the one that fits the best.